# Using Fisher Transform In Multiple Timeframes Simultaniously

Tags: pine-script

I've made good progress merging several indicators together to show them in custom time frames simultaneously. It is working for some indicators.

However, it is not working with the Fisher. I get a "Cannot use mutable variable as an argument for security function" error.

I try to call it with

```
s5 = security(tickerid, tf3,  fish1)
```

The code for Fisher is

```
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")    
high_ = highest(hl2, len)    
low_ = lowest(hl2, len)    
round_(val) => val > .99 ? .999 : val < -.99 ? -.999 : val    
value = 0.0    
value := round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / max(high_ - low_, .001) - .5) + .67 * nz(value[1]))    
fish1 = 0.0    
fish1 := .5 * log((1 + value) / max(1 - value, .001)) + .5 * nz(fish1[1])    
fish2 = fish1[1]
```

Can someone please help? I don't understand where it's going wrong.

I look forward for someone to help me figure this out, and would appreciate it immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the fisher calcs inside the custom function and pass it to the `security` function

```
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")    

round_(val) => val > .99 ? .999 : val < -.99 ? -.999 : val 

f_fisher() =>
    high_ = highest(hl2, len)    
    low_ = lowest(hl2, len)    
    value = 0.0    
    value := round_(.66 * ((hl2 - low_) / max(high_ - low_, .001) - .5) + .67 * nz(value[1]))    
    fish1 = 0.0    
    fish1 := .5 * log((1 + value) / max(1 - value, .001)) + .5 * nz(fish1[1])    
    fish1

mtfFisher = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f_fisher())

plot(mtfFisher)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. I appreciate this very much. It works. Thank you. I'm sorry again. Thanks a lot.